# Create Validation for a custom object line item on an opportunity

Tags: custom-object, opportunity, validation

I have created a custom object called Billing Forecast with a master-detail relationship to the opportunity object.  When an opportunity is closed won I need to ensure that the user enters at least one billing forecast.

A billing forecast consists of a currency field for each month of a year. Each year then becomes a billing forecast. I have tried a couple of different formulas but no luck.

Comment: Is each billing forcast an "annual" forecast ending in Dec or is it year to year from the Opp close-date? Can you give us an example of the formulas you've tried that haven't worked? Do you simply want a sum of the months? We don't know what your page layout looks like to have any idea of the fields or what your needs are.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a rollup summary field on the opportunity object that is the count of Billing Forecast objects.  Then you can use a validation rule that checks that the rollup summary field is greater than 0.  Something like this

```
AND(
     ISCHANGED(StageName),
     TEXT(StageName) = "Closed Won",
     Rollup_Summary_Field__c < 1
)
```

Just need to make sure you put in your own field API Names